# smoother "image brush" on p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I wrote simple code that draws an image around the screen while the mouse is pressed using p5.js.

I've noticed that the flow of created images isn't really smooth, especially when mouse moves faster it doesn't look like an uniform brush but rather many separated images. even when the mouse movement is slower is still possible to see all the different pictures.

Would it be possible to make this effect smoother with p5.js, or should I try another way for achieving this?

```js
let image1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(220);
  image1 = loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg');
};

function mouseDragged() {
  let number = 5;
  image( image1, mouseX - ((image1.width/number) / 2), mouseY - ((image1.height/number) / 2), image1.width / number, image1.height / number);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "smoother"? Should it be faster or should there be an transition?

Comment: I mean that when I drag the mouse rather than seeing 2 images from point A to B I'd like to have many more intermediate steps. So that it would seems like one fluid pictures rather than 2 pics in different positions

Comment: This question has nothing to do with HTML or CSS so I would recommend removing those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I could find a way that kind of solve the issue.
Basically for every mouse movement I draw 50 intermediate steps with the same image. This number can be of course increased but I've noticed a drop of browser performance if those is too high, around 50-200 works fine for me.

```js
let image1;
var firstDrag = true;
var dx;
var dy;
var posx;
var posy;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(220);
  image1 = loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg');
};

function mouseDragged() {
  let number = 5;
  
  //check if it is the first dragging
  //so there's no previous position
  if(firstDrag){
    firstDrag = false;
    prevX = mouseX;
    prevY = mouseY;
  }
  //create 50 intermediates step
  //between previous and current mouse position
  //store in dx and dy the increments to add for each step
  dx = ((mouseX - prevX) / 50);
  dy = ((mouseY - prevY) / 50);
  dxVar = prevX;
  dyVar = prevY;
  
  //drawing a pictures for each intermediate coordinates
  for (let i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
  
    posx = dxVar - ((image1.width/ number) /2);
    posy = dyVar - ((image1.height/ number)/2);
    
    image( image1, posx, posy, image1.width / number, image1.height / number);
    dxVar = dxVar + dx;
    dyVar = dyVar + dy;
  }
  
  //updating the previous mouse position
  prevX = mouseX;
  prevY = mouseY;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of a fixed number of steps, try a variable number of steps depending on how far the mouse has moved this frame for a better result

Comment: I've tried that but unfortunately I got significant performance drops when mouse has moved far

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can think of approaching this problem, the first being increasing the frameRate, meaning there will be more frames every second, resulting in more images being created, which would work in the following way:

```
let image1;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(220);
  image1 = loadImage(
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg"
  );
  frameRate(190);
}

function mouseDragged() {
  let number = 5;
  image(
    image1,
    mouseX - image1.width / number / 2,
    mouseY - image1.height / number / 2,
    image1.width / number,
    image1.height / number
  );
}
```

Another method would be to create a `for` loop for every frame, so every frame, whatever happens is repeated X amounts of time

```
let image1;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(220);
  image1 = loadImage(
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg"
  );
}

function mouseDragged() {
  for(var i = 0; i<2;i++)
    {
  let number = 5;
  image(
    image1,
    mouseX - image1.width / number / 2,
    mouseY - image1.height / number / 2,
    image1.width / number,
    image1.height / number
  );
    }
}
```

I would reccomend the first method because, you can set the number "190" to something very high(1,000), then it'll be at it's top notch performance obviously not at 1,000 Frames per second, but the highest it can do. If change the number in the second method to something very high, not only will it not make it faster, it'll make it terribly slow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried already with the frameRate function but it doesn't seem to effect the code in any way (even with very high values). Do you know why it does that?

Comment: Even with very high values, your device can't handle having it at very high values, so it processing it at the highest framerate it can manage. If your device isn't high-end, then the average Frames Per Second wouldn't be higher, if it can't reach "X", making "X" higher wouldn't make a difference. In this case, I would recommend my second method, which is better if this is your personal program, you can guess and check (Should take 5 minutes max with the process of elimination), and find the perfect number of loops per frame for your device.

Comment: By the way, in Stack Overflow it's customary to accept an answer if your problem is solved, you can do it by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer. This is so people know there's already an answer. The upvote button is so others with the same question find the best answer if there are multiple. Or if the answer is a good answer.

Comment: I know thanks, it's just that I haven't had time yet to test the anwser and check if that works for me. I'll reply as soon as I can! thank you

Comment: No problem, feel free to take your time and ask me any questions if my answer didn't solve your problem.